# Integrate OpenID Connect with Kerberos

Tags: openid-connect, kerberos

how can I integrate applications and services that use OpenID Connect and OAuth to authorize requests use the access token to access services that have Kerberos protection.

I have a longer description here: [OpenID Connect / OAuth / Kerberos](https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vSTpbHs0V9uGpmsze9LgPp0WDFQexjR2r3-ZMxy4pc2huKiOTaZ1gN5kwtR0soSGLjM40UGyRhAnxkk/pub)

Comment: You're going to need to copy that description here, otherwise you're going to get downvoted and closed. Besides the fact that the link requires permissions to access, it could disappear making the context of this question disappear so anyone looking at it in the future wont be able to understand it.

Comment: Hi Steve, I would like to add it, but then StackOverflow complains that it is not focussed enough. Any suggestions?